# How to measure PCI-Express bus usage?

Tags: linux, kernel, freebsd, monitoring, pci

I'm looking for a way to find out if PCIe bus is the bottleneck or not.

It's not a problem to measure how much bytes was transferred through any particular NIC:

[image]

Is there a way to find how much data was transferred to all the other PCIe devices (hard drives, video cards, etc.)?

Comment: Anybody managed to get hold of [pcitop](https://web.archive.org/web/20130123151613/http://pcitop.berlios.de/) before berlios went offline?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas it's available [at GitHub](https://github.com/BackupTheBerlios/pcitop). But it seems to only support IA64, not x86/x86_64.

Answer (score 2):

I have been investigating this as well, yet so far, I have had no luck.  The good news is that the Intel specsheets i've looked at include accessible registers for some of this.  I would have to create a kernel module to expose this to the /proc or /sys filesystem.  It would be way more convenient if this already existed though.

Software aside, the other solution would be to get a hardware solution.  I've seen products that you plug into an empty slot to get this information.  And of course, an oscilloscope to manually investigate as well.